# Control continuous servo motor with Raspberry Pi and Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, servo

I am trying to control my continuous servo motor using this code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
p = GPIO.PWM(17, 50)
p.start(7.5)
try:
        while True:
                p.ChangeDutyCycle(7.5)
                time.sleep(1)
                p.ChangeDutyCycle(12.5)
                time.sleep(1)
                p.ChangeDutyCycle(2.5)
                time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Servo operates correctly as the code sometimes and other it works randomly for the same code. I use another power source for the motor.

I don't think motor is damaged because I use Arduino to control the servo and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If by 'works randomly' you mean 'it moves to roughly the right place, but wobbles around a lot' then the problem will be with the Raspberry Pi's  Software Pulse-width Modulation (PWM)

The servo needs a consistent pulse to behave consistently, more accurate than the Pi's software can provide.  So the pulse is slightly inconsistent which manifests itself in a 'jitter' (in a continuous servo this would be a random change of speed around the correct speed)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @JeffUK's answer above -- and I know it's not a software thing, but still germain -- is *make sure your servo (even though you say it's powered by another source) and the Pi* **share a common ground connection**.  A floating ground can cause all sorts of unpredictable behaviors.  It's very common for us software folks to forget that :) little detail when hooking up external devices.

Comment: Thanks. I solved problem by using gpio.cleanup() in every loop I use.